# Any 7-bit way to write ä (umlaut-a) without "

Tags: accents, input-encodings

I'm using a batch file to generate a small LaTeX input file. I cannot use proper umlauts, but the batch file has problems with `"` as text and I want to produce the word `März`.

Is there any way in LaTeX to produce what would otherwise be written as `M\"arz`

Comment: simplest is to write `\usepackage{local}` in the preamble and use `\marz` then `local.sty` can have `\newcommand\marz{M\"arz}`

Comment: Sounds like you need to escape the backlash in front of `"`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This works:

```
M\^^22arz
```

Indeed TeX interprets `^^xy` (where `x` and `y` are digits or `abcdef`) as the character having `"xy` (hexadecimal) ASCII code. Since the character code of `"` is 34, hexadecimal 22, typing `\^^22` is the same as typing `\"`. This translation happens before TeX starts to make tokens.